# What does 「きみをしたって きたというが」 mean?

Tags: translation, manga

I have found it in a manga in a situation that there is a news reporter asking the following sentence to a boy whom the reporter thought that he is living in a ruin building with a group of little kids.

ここにいる少年たちは　みんな　**きみをしたって　きたというが**　ほんとうですか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ここにいる少年達はみんな君を**慕って**来たというが、本当ですか?

There is a transitive verb [慕【した】う](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%85%95%E3%81%86) which means *to yearn for*.

Comment: Just to add my opinion, "adore" or "look up to" would probably be a better translation.