# What does the word 「したって　こられりゃ」 mean?

Tags: words, manga

Here is the sentence including the word.

しかし　里子といってもこのきずついた子どもたちをほんとうにいたわれるおとななんていやしない　なんとなくいびり出されてそこをとび出し　また　兄貴かぶのおれをしたってあつまってきちまったんだ **したって　こられりゃ**おれも男さ

Comment: Again, this is not a single word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a colloquial/slurred way of saying [慕]{した}ってこ(来)られれば, "If/when you are admired/followed (by these kids)". 慕ってこられる is the passive of 慕ってくる, to respect, admire, and/or follow.

Comment: つい最近同じような質問してるやん・・・　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24719/what-does-the-sentence-%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BF%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C-mean